# Find $f$ such that $\boldsymbol{a}=\boldsymbol{a}(f)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $d=\operatorname{dim} V$, and let $f: V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation. We associate to $f$ the sequence $\boldsymbol{a}(f)=\left(a_{n}\right){n \in \mathbb{N}{0}}$ given by $a_{n}=\operatorname{dim} \operatorname{ker} f^{n}$. Prove the following statements.

a) For each $n \geq 0$, $a_{n} \leq a_{n+1}$.

b) For each $n \geq 0$, $a_{n+2}-a_{n+1} \leq a_{n+1}-a_{n}$.

c) If $n \geq d$, then $a_{n+1}=a_{n} \leq d$.

d) For any sequence $\boldsymbol{a}$ that satisfies the three previous properties, there exists a linear transformation $f: V \rightarrow V$ such that $\boldsymbol{a}=\boldsymbol{a}(f)$

I had prove $a, \ b$ and $c$, but pretty much stuck with $d$.

I know that basically what I have to do is showing that there exist an f such that the sequence of the dimension of its kernels are non-decreasing and bounded, which doesn't seem hard. But I think that for the prove to be complete I would have to construct also that $f$.

This is what I'm struggling with, since the only thing that came to my mind to do it was constructing it based on its Jordan Blocks, increasing the dimension of the kernel taking into account the size of the blocks relating them to the sequence itself. But I don't remember that much of Jordan Blocks either so I wouldn't really know how to proceed that way, it was just a possibility.

Comment: I am confused about your statement c) though. What is $d$?

Comment: The dimension of V, it's literally in the first sentence haha